# Why is my profile card not centering in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to center my profile card but I can't get it to freakin center. How can I center this card so it is in the middle of the page? I tried `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` and those should of worked so I'm not sure why they aren't working.

**mingle.html**

```
   {% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}


{% block styles %}

body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
*:hover{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
section{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background: #fff;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    padding:30px 0;
}
h1{float:left; width:100%; color:#232323; margin-bottom:30px; font-size: 14px;}
h1 span{font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; display:block; font-size:45px; text-transform:none; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:30px; font-weight:700}
h1 a{color:#131313; font-weight:bold;}

/*Profile Card 5*/

.profile-card-5{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;



}
.profile-card-5 .btn{
    border-radius:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:7px 20px;
}
.profile-card-5 .card-img-block {
    width: 91%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;

}
.profile-card-5 .card-img-block img{
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
}
.profile-card-5 h5{
    color:#4E5E30;
    font-weight:600;
}
.profile-card-5 p{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:300;
}
.profile-card-5 .btn-primary{
    background-color:#4E5E30;
    border-color:#4E5E30;
}


{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<section>
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
                <div class="card profile-card-5">
                    <div class="card-img-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517832207067-4db24a2ae47c" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body pt-0">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Florence Garza</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="mt-3 w-100 float-left text-center"><strong>Card with Floting Picture</strong></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from the class `col-md-3` that you're using the framework **Bootstrap**.

Bootstrap *divides* the page into 12 columns, your card wrapper has the class `col-md-3`, which means its width is equal to 3 of those 12 columns. If you inspect your page you'll see the calculated style:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .col-md-3 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
 }
}
```

You've added `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` to the inner `<div>`, that's it doesn't work. You should add them to the `<div>` with class `.col-md-3`.

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
*:hover{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
section{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background: #fff;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    padding:30px 0;
}
h1{float:left; width:100%; color:#232323; margin-bottom:30px; font-size: 14px;}
h1 span{font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; display:block; font-size:45px; text-transform:none; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:30px; font-weight:700}
h1 a{color:#131313; font-weight:bold;}
 .col-md-3 { margin:0 auto;}
/*Profile Card 5*/
.profile-card-5{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.profile-card-5 .btn{
    border-radius:2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:7px 20px;
}
.profile-card-5 .card-img-block {
    width: 91%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;

}
.profile-card-5 .card-img-block img{
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
}
.profile-card-5 h5{
    color:#4E5E30;
    font-weight:600;
}
.profile-card-5 p{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:300;
}
.profile-card-5 .btn-primary{
    background-color:#4E5E30;
    border-color:#4E5E30;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
                <div class="card profile-card-5">
                    <div class="card-img-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517832207067-4db24a2ae47c" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body pt-0">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Florence Garza</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="mt-3 w-100 float-left text-center"><strong>Card with Floting Picture</strong></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's also a link to a live [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/LYGxMxw).

**EDIT**

What I've added in your code is:

```css
.col-md-3 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I will advise to add another class, instead you applying the style directly to `.col-md-3`.

Comment: Well, it totally works so thank you. But I'm still not clear exactly where you changed the code to make it work.

Comment: @Rez I've updated my answer, just move the "margin-left/right: auto;" to div.col-md-3

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
section{
display: grid;
}

section > div {
justify-self: center;
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.